# Python integration with excel

Tags: python, excel, vba, excel-formula

I have an excel model which includes a "normal random number" as an input; so, anytime I hit F9 (refresh/calculate), I get a new output since one of the inputs (i.e., the normal random number) changes.

I generally use VBA to just refresh/calculate the worksheet repeatedly and save the different outputs in an array or something; however, this method gets very slow if I need to do a lot of simulations (100k or 1 million).

I was wondering if anyone can suggest a better way for this?
The model is pretty big so building it completely in Python would be a challenge - if there is a way we can keep the model in excel and use python (or anything else?) for refreshing and saving the output, that would be great.

Thank you!

Comment: With Python. Get rid of Excel, it's completely the wrong tool for this.

Comment: Building it completely in Python or virtually any other suitable framework (not Excel) is exactly what you should do. It's quite common to re-build Excel models in something more appropriate as they get bigger, many people went there.